# Getting values from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have ended up with a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
               adm1    per_area_adm1
0          campeche  [2.57978273338]
1           chiapas  [10.9970300459]
```

Is there a way to get the values from `per_area_adm1` column? I can do `df['per_area_adm1'].values` but that provides an array of lists

Comment: sorry, I meant I used .values but that does not work. I will update question

Comment: what is your expected out put ?

Comment: expected output should be an array of values and not array of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, `df.apply(operator.itemgetter)`:

```
In [1026]: import operator

In [1027]: df.per_area_adm1.apply(operator.itemgetter(0)).values
Out[1027]: array([  2.57978273,  10.99703005])
```

Answer (score 3):

If each list contains only one element, you can use `.str[0]`:

```
df.per_area_adm1.str[0]

#0     2.579783
#1    10.997030
#Name: per_area_adm1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to reduce the list of lists to just a list

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in df['per_area_adm1'].values for item in sublist]
print(flat_list)
```

Reference: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)